# animating cards enter in grid in swiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, transition

I have a custom Grid that I have built it in SwiftUI and I have 12 cards in the model. When iPhone launches the grid loads up these 12 cards onto the screen. However, I want the cards to slide in from random positions into their respective position. I am new to SwiftUI and I'm having trouble understanding animation and transition. If I have to use @State then how do I sync that to some variable in the model.
Here is the code, this is the main view. I have omitted var body for easier focus:

```
Grid(self.setGameViewModel.playingTwelveSetCards) { setCard in
    SetCardView(setCard: setCard)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                self.setGameViewModel.choose(setCard: setCard)
            }
         }
}
```

here is CardView:

```
ZStack {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        .stroke(isSelected ? Color.black : Color.gray, lineWidth: lineWidth)
    VStack {
        ForEach(0..<count) { _ in
            self.getShapes(color: color)
        }
    }
}
.padding(5)
.scaleEffect(isSelected ? 1.07 : 1)
```

`self.setGameViewModel.playingTwelveSetCards` contains 12 set cards extracted from the viewModel, as soon as the app launches `playingTwelveSetCards` is populated with 12 set cards and Grid just gets drawn but I don't want cards just to appear I want them to slide from random positions for that I have this little helper function

```
func generateRandomNumberForOffset() -> CGFloat {
    CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(201) + 100)
}
```

Where should I apply transition and animation?